# How to apply operations (like filter, add column, etc) to a R.data_frame? (R type provider)

Tags: r, f#, type-providers

On R, you can easily:

filter:

```
frame <- frame[frame$some_column>0, ]
```

add a column:

```
frame$new_column <- frame$some_column * 100
```

Select unique elements:

```
unique(frame$some_column)
```

How can you achieve this with R Provider?

Comment: If you do lots of data frame work in F#, you might be interested in Deedle, which also has nice R interop via the R type provider: http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/rinterop.html

Comment: @TomasPetricek I checked very quick Deedle and I didn't see it uses R (which is a requirement for the project). I will translate the R code into F# via Deedle. Thanks!

Comment: @TomasPetricek One thing led to another and now I'm checking FsLab, looks great!

Answer (score 2):

When you realize how heavily the R Provider relies on R.Net, it is easy to look on the internet and realize that you can do stuff like this:

```
let dataFrame = //some R.data_frame
let e = REngine.GetInstance()
e.SetSymbol("dataFrame", dataFrame)
e.Evaluate("unique(dataFrame$some_column)").GetValue<double[]>()
e.Evaluate("dataFrame$new_column <- dataFrame$some_column * 1000")
```